# Google analytics replace a single repeating character from URL

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-search-console

I have the below request URI in google analytics

```
/search?q=text1-text2-text3
/search?q=menu
/search?q=test
/search?q=text23-text21-text22
/search?q=text244-text212
/search?q=Pens
```

I need to replace the `-` to a `+` either by using a advanced filter or a search and replace.
I tried to use `\b-\b` but the output was wrong. Can someone help me with the regex?

Comment: Is the syntax different for google analytics? In other regex engines `/-/g` would work

Comment: You just replace `-` with `+`. That must be enough.

Comment: So there are somethings that are not allowed in GA w.r.t regex (I think). Both the above doen not work because it should also search for the beginning `/search?q=` text

Comment: Any help here??